# Indexeddb in Chrome on IOS - when available?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, indexeddb

Does anyone know when or how Indexeddb will be available in Chrome on IOS?
Indexeddb works well in mobile Chrome on Android devices!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chrome for iOS is not really the same as Chrome on other platforms due to restrictions in iOS. It's really just a wrapper around the standard iOS web browser control. This means it's restricted to *similar* restrictions and iOS WebKit (there's a few other restrictions to do with JS optimisation and such).

Because of that you're at the mercy of iOS WebKit support for IndexedDB and it's unclear as to when that'll come. In the mean time you can always use the [IndexedDB polyfill](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) which wraps WebSQL, which is supported according to [haz.io](http://haz.io).

*Update: As @x3m has pointed out iOS8 will be adding IndexedDB support so on iOS and Safari Desktop IndexedDB will be supported.*

Comment: Apple is adding IndexedDb support in iOS 8. According to http://caniuse.com/indexeddb iOS Safari version 8 will support IndexedDb, hopefully Chrome on iOS will support IndexedDb soon also.

Comment: @x3m That comes down to how the WebView is exposed in iOS8. I've read that they are taking the restrictions that previously were on it (that crippled the JavaScript performance) but I haven't had any opportunity to test it for what other support you get.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth I did some tests on iOS 8 beta 5 for who ever is interested.

Safari (Chrome is not optimized for iOS 8 yet) was able to store 1GB (1024MB exactly) of data in Indexed DB, but only in chunks of 10MB at a time